# Getting values from non hidden cells sequentially in excel

Tags: excel, row, hidden, vba

I am trying to generate a list of data based on the contents of a group of filtered cells. First (in code not included), users select a criterion from a list box, which filters a list of 800 accounts down to the number that meet that criterion. From there, I need to grab the value from Column a and the row that corresponds to the visible cells. The issue is that I can't do a straight reference to the row, because when the rows are hidden, it is no longer a 1,2,3,4 etc sequential list. Here is the code I have, I know exactly where I need to specify the rows, just not how to do so

```
Sub AllProviders_Click()

Dim i As Integer
Dim vCount As Integer

vCount = Range("E18:E817").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count
MsgBox vCount 'for debugging


For i = 1 To vCount
    Sheets("Provider Output").Cells(3, 2 + i) = 'and this is where I have no idea
Next i
End Sub
```

When the sub is run, the number of cells that are visible is stored in vCount, which is used to specify how many columns of data are going to be filled. My issue is line 7, where I need to specify the cells to pull.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Range("A18:A817").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
  Sheets("Provider Output").Cells(3, 3)
```

Edit: if that's not working for you then maybe try this -

```
Sub AllProviders_Click()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim c As Range

    i = 1
    For Each c In Range("E18:E817").Cells
        If Not c.EntireRow.Hidden Then
            Sheets("Provider Output").Cells(3, 2 + i) = c.EntireRow.Cells(1).Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim! Do you mean:
 Sheets("Provider Output").Cells(3, 2 + i) = Range("A18:A817").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).CopySheets("Provider Output").Cells(3, 3)


If so it throws an error object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: I meant exactly what I posted

Comment: In that case while I appreciate your help it did not function as intended. Perhaps I should state my intent a different way. I have a filtered list that contains lets say 3 rows of data. While normally I could use cells(1+i, 1) to move down the list, this would only move from row 1 to 2 to 3, but since the cells are hidden, it may actually need to move to row 1 to 6 to 320. How can I move down the list of rows irrespective of their actual index but relative to their visibility.